# Kotlin: Room DB using SUM query in non-activity class/calculations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao, android-livedata

I'm relatively new to `Kotlin` and I'm working on a project for school.  I've gotten stuck on something I can't figure out for a couple days now, either because I'm not just understanding how it works or I just don't know what to search for.  I'm building an app for simple budget tracking, and using `Room DB` to allow the user to enter and store their expenses.  I've gotten most of the app built and working, and have the DB, a `DAO`, a `Repository` and a `ViewModel`.  I've successfully written a `Query` that returns the sum through a `LiveData<Double>`.  I've managed to get this sum value to display through both a `Toast` message and in a `TextView` in the `MainActivity` (but the TV doesn't update on load, only after launching the activity for modifying the DB entries for the first time).

If it's possible, I want to be able to take this sum and store it inside a separate class I've written for calculation functions, and have it update whenever a user enters or deletes something from the DB.  Or preferably, have the non-activity class call this sum whenever the class's relevant functions are called.  I don't seem to understand how to get this value from anywhere but the `MainActivity`.  Everything I've searched and read has sections of code which I think I understand, such as `observeForever` which require an application parameter, or they're over my head because it's just code snippets which I can't wrap my head around how they fit together.

Here is what I have so far:

My Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "expenses")
data class Expenses (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    val id: Int,
    val expDesc: String,
    val expAmount: Double

)
```

My DAO:

```
@Dao
interface Dao {


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addData(expenses: Expenses)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM expenses ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<Expenses>>

    @Query("SELECT SUM(expAmount) as expenseSum FROM expenses")
    fun getExpenseSum(): LiveData<Double>


    @Update
    suspend fun updateExpense(expenses: Expenses)


    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteData(expenses: Expenses)


    @Query("DELETE FROM expenses")
    suspend fun deleteAllData()

}
```

My Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Expenses::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class Database:RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dao(): Dao

    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
        abstract fun userDao(): Dao?
    }


    companion object{

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: com.example.finalproject.roomDB.Database? = null


        fun getDatabase(context: Context): com.example.finalproject.roomDB.Database {
            val instance = INSTANCE

            if(instance != null){
                return instance
            }

            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        com.example.finalproject.roomDB.Database::class.java,
                        "expenses").build()

                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Repository:

```
class Repository(private val dao: Dao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Expenses>> = dao.readAllData()
    val getExpenseSum: LiveData<Double> = dao.getExpenseSum()

    suspend fun addData(expenses: Expenses){
        dao.addData(expenses)
    }

    suspend fun updateData(expenses: Expenses){
        dao.updateExpense(expenses)
    }

    suspend fun deleteData(expenses: Expenses){
        dao.deleteData(expenses)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllData(){
        dao.deleteAllData()
    }

}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Expenses>>
    val getExpenseSum: LiveData<Double>
    private val repository: Repository

    init{
        val dao = Database.getDatabase(application).dao()
        repository = Repository(dao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
        getExpenseSum = repository.getExpenseSum
    }

    fun addData(expenses: Expenses){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addData(expenses)
        }
    }

    fun updateData(expenses: Expenses){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.updateData(expenses) }
    }

    fun deleteData(expenses: Expenses){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.deleteData(expenses) }
    }

    fun deleteAllData(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.deleteAllData() }
    }

}
```

My currently relevant part of the MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
    var sumTotal: Double = 0.0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val expenseViewButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.expViewButton)
        val incomeViewButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.incViewButton)
        val goalsViewButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goalsViewButton)
        val expectedExpAmtView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.expectedExpAmt)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application).create(ViewModel::class.java)

        //This observer successfully casts the LiveData<Double> to a Double and updates whenever changed 
        val sumObserver = Observer<Double> { expSumDbl -> sumTotal = expSumDbl }
        viewModel.getExpenseSum.observe(this, sumObserver)
        expectedExpAmtView.text = getString(R.string.monthly_expected_ExpAmt, sumTotal.toString())

        expenseViewButton.setOnClickListener{
            val myIntent: Intent = Intent(this, ExpenseActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(myIntent)
        }

        incomeViewButton.setOnClickListener{
            val myIntent: Intent = Intent(this, IncomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(myIntent)
        }

        //This successfully displays the correct sum whenever the button is pressed
        goalsViewButton.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, sumTotal.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

So `sumTotal` is the value from `MainActivity` that I'd like to get in a different non-activity class* for calculations that won't affect the DB at all, only text views.  I'd also like the `TextView` that is being updated to always be up-to-date, including when the app launches.  If anyone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong and/or need to do differently I'd really appreciate it.

*Specifically at the moment, I have a budget class which handles getting things like income, entered into editText fields, and calculating how much that translates into on a monthly basis.  I'd like to take the sum from the DB entries and subtract it from whatever that total becomes in the budget class and return the result.  I might want to do other (undecided) things later with the sum, which is why I want to store it in a variable.

Comment: Please be more specific on what "different non-activity class" is that. It will help to provider a better answer.

Comment: Updated the post: Specifically at the moment, I have a budget class which handles getting things like income, entered into editText fields, and calculating how much that translates into on a monthly basis.  I'd like to take the sum from the DB entries and subtract it from whatever that total becomes in the budget class and return the result.  I might want to do other (undecided) things later with the sum, which is why I want to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `sumTotal` in `MainActivity` actually comes from `Repository.getExpenseSum`, so instead of sharing that variable to another class, it might be easier to call the repository method again from the other class. Actually, I wouldn't even recommend having that variable `sumTotal` in your Activity, it's better to rely on `ViewModel` only, but that's a different topic.

You interface `Dao` contains the method:

```
fun getExpenseSum(): LiveData<Double>
```

which returns a `LiveData`. If you want to observe a `LiveData`, you need to have a `LifecycleOwner` so the `LiveData` knows when it should start and stop emitting updates (or you can `observeForever`, but you need to know yourself when to stop observing it).

In your budget class, assuming it's not a Fragment/Activity, you won't have a `LifecycleOwner`, that's why one suggestion for you issue is to create another method in `Dao`:

```
fun getExpenseSum(): Double
```

Notice the lack of `LiveData`. That method will return a double whenever you call it, synchronously, but it needs to be executed on a background thread. You can call that method in your budget class and get that value there.

Lastly, I don't think you should be calling those DB methods in some "regular" classes, you should pass those variables when creating an instance of the budget class. It's much easier to deal with `LiveData`/background thread when you're on the standard Android classes, and just pass the values to other classes that need it, instead of making them query the repository themselves.